# while redirecting to a view this error happens:invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, django

in urls.py :

```
(r'^airAgency/(?P<key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/edittour/(?P<tour_id>\d+)/$','airAgency.views.edittour'),
```

in views.py :

```
     tour.save()
 ang=Agent.objects.get(pk=key)
 return HttpResponseRedirect('airAgency/%s/edittour/%i/edittour.html' % (agn.WebSite,tour.pk))
```

note: tour is a form,after saving form tour pk is used to pass to edittour.html
but when redirecting to edittour.html it has this error:

```
ValueError at /airAgency/mastane/addtour/ 
    invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'mastane' 
Request Method: POST 
Request URL: 127.0.0.1:8080/airAgency/mastane/addtour 
Django Version: 1.3 
Exception Type: ValueError 
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'mastane' 
Exception Location: C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields_init_.py in get_prep_value, line 479
Python Executable: C:\Python26\python.exe
```

Comment: In the future, please show the whole traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `tour.pk` can't be converted to an integer by the `%i` format specifier.

It needs to be a string containing an integer (with or without a sign, ignores leading zeros), a numeric type like `float`, or a class with an `__int__` method.

Comment: @Asma Well, what is the value of `tour.pk`? Give a real example that results in that error.

Comment: I think django define the pk as integer.

Comment: @Asma It's not an integer or you wouldn't get the error. You need to actually debug it and see what you're getting. What does `print tour.pk` there show?

Comment: let me describe more.first of all I'm in this page:/airAgency/mastane/addtour/ then I click a button and wanna redirect to the url I mentioned before,but the error is for the current url,not for url I wanna redirect to!! the current url in yrls.py is defined like this: (r'^airAgency/(?P<key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/addtour/$','airAgency.views.addtour'),

Comment: @Asma So, what line does the error actually occur on? Show more code, and ___show the whole traceback___.

Comment: ValueError at /airAgency/mastane/addtour/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'mastane'

Request Method:  POST
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8080/airAgency/mastane/addtour/
Django Version:  1.3
Exception Type:  ValueError
Exception Value:  

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'mastane'

Exception Location:  C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 479
Python Executable:  C:\Python26\python.exe

Comment: @Asma OK. So like I said, you've got `'mastane'` as `tour.pk`. What variable is storing the actual tour key you're looking for? You haven't shown me enough code to help with that. The reason the error is on the `add` page not the `edit` page is that the error happens __before__ the `add` page is able to send the redirect header to the `edit` page.

Comment: ok,that problem was solved,now I have another problem.when I wanna redirect to edittour,HttpResponseRedirect append edittour Url to the current url,what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Asma If you have another question, you need to ask it separately. Comments aren't for asking new questions. I also can't tell at all what it is you're trying to ask there. If you post another question, please show code, describe your problem clearly, show the __full traceback__, properly formatted, and ask a clear question. Please remember to accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: this worked right to me: HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('airAgency.views.edittour', args=[agn.WebSite,tour.pk]))

Answer (score 1):

As agf said, you can get around your problem by simply replacing this line :

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('airAgency/%s/edittour/%s/edittour.html' % (agn.WebSite,str(tour.pk)))
```

assuming `tour.pk` is greater (or equal) than 0...

Comment: See the full traceback added to the question. This doesn't solve his problem, as doing this won't result in a valid URL.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
ang=Agent.objects.get(pk=key)
...% (agn.WebSite
```

and as @agf pointed out in the comments it appears that your value of `tour.pk` is 'mastane' instead of an integer.

Comment: That's certainly a copy / paste error or it never would have gotten to the `invalid literal...` error.